# NullPointerException while setting Image in imageView from Bitmap?

Tags: android, xml, nullpointerexception, expansion

I am Using APK Expansion File from http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html

CODE :

```
String[] path= getAPKExpansionFiles(this,2,0);
ZipResourceFile expansionFile;
try {
        expansionFile = new ZipResourceFile(path[0]);
        InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream("assets/Tablet/Chester_the_cat/chester_the_cat_2.png");
        Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileStream);
            iv_new=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_new);
            iv_new.setImageBitmap(bit);
```

and m getting this NullPointerException in this line

```
   iv_new.setImageBitmap(bit);
```

and in XML my ImageView is :

```
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/iv_new"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Please debug is iv_new is null or bit is null there at that line ?

Comment: ok i will try this nd let u know d result :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you call the `setContentView(View)` with the layout which contains the ImageView?

Comment: Please check this again, because he can not find the view in the inflated layout. (The findViewById returns null means this view you want isn't inflated)

Comment: i check it again but i mention in it

Comment: is it possible to load Bitmap content in webview  ?

Comment: I guess yes, you should pass the location of the bitmap as url. But you shouldn't do that. Try figuring out what you did wrong :)